# I want my div's to overlap

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm trying to overlap some images, but whatever combination of positions I try, it doesn't seem to work.

**this is the HTML**

```
<li class="six">

<img class="06a" src="../inhouds/images/page06a.png"> 
<img class="06b" src="../inhouds/images/page06b.png">
<img class="06c" src="../inhouds/images/page06c.png">

</li>
```

**this is the CSS**

```
.06a {
position:absolute;
z-index: 250;
}

.06b {
position:absolute;
z-index: 260;
margin-left: 50px;
}

.06c {
position:absolute;
z-index: 270;
margin-left: 100px;
}
```

I hope someone can help me out!

Comment: 1) start your id or class with a letter 2) take them out of the li

Comment: Start here www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: also if you're using position: absolute, why not just use left and top instead of silly margins?

Comment: @mplungjan I think you mean class. Since they used classes in there's.

Comment: Can you show an image of what you want to achieve? Even one done in paint is fine.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/7atdN/

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this kind of overlap  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KWgc4/)

Change markup to better semantic(alphabets for class,not numbers) :

```
<li class="six">
     <img class="a" src="http://www.jonathanjeter.com/images/Square_200x200.png" />
     <img class="b" src="http://www.jonathanjeter.com/images/Square_200x200.png" />
     <img class="c" src="http://www.jonathanjeter.com/images/Square_200x200.png" />
</li>
```

CSS i did

```
li {
    list-style:none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Click here for a working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/ywXDh/)**

Do not start classnames with numbers. Use `left` instead of `margin-left` as you are using absolute positioning.

**HTML**

```
<img class="a06a" src="http://i.imgur.com/JMCU8.jpg"> 
<img class="a06b" src="http://i.imgur.com/UjdNhhO.jpg">
<img class="a06c" src="http://i.imgur.com/KOfaU.jpg">
```

**CSS**

```
.a06a {
position:absolute;
z-index: 250;
}

.a06b {
position:absolute;
z-index: 260;
left: 50px;
}

.a06c {
position:absolute;
z-index: 270;
left: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/WSZvb/) is a nice and clean example to understand how it works

CSS

```
.box1, .box2, .box3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}

.box2 {
    background: green;
    left: 50px;
}

.box3 {
    background: blue;
    left: 100px;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="conatiner">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
    <div class="box3"></div>
</div>
```

For something that you position absolute you should always have `top` and `left` defined.